# format_datetime() in Kusto for datetime with minutes and secounds as 00

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In the [azure data explorer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats), there is a lot of supported formats but not the one that i am looking for.

What I need is to format the datetime like `"yyyy-MM-dd HH"` to set the minutes and seconds as 0

**Input datetime**

```
2020-04-21T17:44:27.6825985Z
```

**expected results**

```
2020-04-21 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [`bin()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction) to round down to the hour, and if you still need to remove the datetime parts lower than seconds, you can use `substring()` (or `format_datetime()`). e.g.:

```
print d = datetime(2020-04-21T17:44:27.6825985Z)
| extend h = bin(d, 1h)
| extend h2 = substring(h, 0, 19)
```

Answer (score 3):

hmm, if you always just want the rest to be 0, can you just use string concatenation?

```
let d = datetime(2020-04-21T17:44:27.6825985Z);
print strcat(format_datetime(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH"), ":00:00")
```

the above code will give you the result of

```
2020-04-21 17:00:00
```

Comment: Works good with day, hour, but not with minute. the issue is the datetime is not correct i.e. if the time is 2020-04-21T17:44:27 the return result will be 2020-04-21T05:44:27